# Threading and Multiprocessing os modules in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, operating-system, multiprocessing

I'm trying to create multiple files which will be analyzed with a stand-alone program as part of a high throughput analysis written in python.

```
for foo in X:
    write foo_file
    os.system(run_program foo_file)
```

For 15,000 distinct individual files this will run faster if I can run them on multiple cores, but I don't want to swamp my server.  How do I set up multiple threads for to run in os but put a maximum on the number of threads open at once?  I'm not worried about speed of spawning processes as the runtime is defined by an external program standard in my field.

I've looked at documentation for threading and multiprocessing and gotten overwhelmed.

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to limit the total number of processes spawned is to use a [multiprocessing pool](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

A simple example demonstrating a multiprocessing pool is:

**test.py**

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
# @NOTE: The two imports below are for demo purposes and won't be necessary in
# your final program
import random
import time

def writeOut(index):
    """ A function which prints a start message, delays for a random interval and then
        prints a finish message
    """
    delay = random.randint(1,5)                                                                                                                                             
    print("Starting process #{0}".format(index))
    time.sleep(delay)
    print("Finished process #{0} which delayed for {1}s.".format(index, delay))

# Create a process pool with a maximum of 10 worker processes
pool = Pool(processes=10)
# Map our function to a data set - number 1 through 20
pool.map(writeOut, range(20))
```

Which should give you an output similar to:

```
[mike@tester ~]$ python test.py 
Starting process #0
Starting process #2
Starting process #3
Starting process #1
Starting process #4
Starting process #5
Starting process #6
Starting process #7
Starting process #8
Starting process #9
Finished process #2 which delayed for 1s.
Starting process #10
Finished process #7 which delayed for 1s.
Finished process #6 which delayed for 1s.
Starting process #11
Starting process #12
Finished process #9 which delayed for 2s.
Finished process #12 which delayed for 1s.
Starting process #13
Starting process #14
Finished process #1 which delayed for 3s.
Finished process #5 which delayed for 3s.
Starting process #15
Starting process #16
Finished process #8 which delayed for 3s.
Starting process #17
Finished process #4 which delayed for 4s.
Starting process #18
Finished process #10 which delayed for 3s.
Finished process #13 which delayed for 2s.
Starting process #19
Finished process #0 which delayed for 5s.
Finished process #3 which delayed for 5s.
Finished process #11 which delayed for 4s.
Finished process #15 which delayed for 2s.
Finished process #16 which delayed for 2s.
Finished process #18 which delayed for 2s.
Finished process #14 which delayed for 4s.
Finished process #17 which delayed for 5s.
Finished process #19 which delayed for 5s.
```

As you can see the first ten processes kick off and then each subsequent process only starts as soon as another process pool worker is done (becomes available). Using multiple processes (as opposed to multiple threads) bypasses the [global interpreter lock (GIL)](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

To get this example code to work with your task you'll need to write a file output function and pass it and the iterable of file data to write to `pool.map()` in place of `writeOut` and `range(20)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class ThreadWriteFile(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue_to_write, queue_to_run):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue_to_write = queue_to_write
        self.queue_to_run = queue_to_run

    def run(self):
        while True:
            foo_file = self.queue_to_write.get()
            write foo_file
            self.queue_to_run.put(foo_file)
            self.queue_to_write.task_done()

class ThreadRunProgram(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue_to_run):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue_to_run = queue_to_run

    def run(self):
        while True:
            foo_file = self.queue_to_run.get()
            os.system(run_program foo_file)
            self.queue_to_run.task_done()

queue_to_write = Queue.Queue()
queue_to_run = Queue.Queue()

for foo in X:
    twf = ThreadWriteFile(queue_to_write, queue_to_run)
    twf.daemon = True
    twf.start()
    queue_to_write.put(foo)

    trf = ThreadRunProgram(queue_to_run)
    trf.daemon = True
    trf.start()

queue_to_write.join()
queue_to_run.join()
```

Comment: Will the GIL affect this significantly?

Comment: os.system releases GIL, so it should not be an issue. It is better to use multithreading.pool.Pool or  multithreading.pool.ThreadPool though